# How to upload images to an ExpressJS server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I feel like I'm losing my mind trying to solve this problem. I'm a fairly new web developer (this is like my third real project) and I'm trying to create a one-page application with image upload functionality. I have been using AJAX for front-end/back-end communication, so my first question would be is it possible to send images using AJAX? I've heard some people say it is and some say it isn't, without a ton of detail as to why, or if it is, how.

I've been looking into other ways to do this and have found very little that actually contained enough detail/context to implement. I've managed to get something that techically works using a basic HTML form and the multer npm package, which looks like this:

```
editModal.innerHTML =   "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + response[0].image_loc + "'><br>" +
                        "<form method='post' action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='edit_post_form'>" +
                        "   Select a new thumbnail<input type='file' id='post_thumbnail' name='file'><br>" +
                        "   Title<input type='text' id='post_title' name='title' value='" + response[0].title + "'><br>" +
                        "   Description<input type='text' id='post_desc' name='description' value='" + response[0].description + "'><br>" +
                        "   Price<input type='text' id='post_price' name='price' value='" + response[0].price + "'><br>" +
                        "   <button type='submit' class='submit' id='submit_post_edit'>Submit</button>" +
                        "   <button type='button' class='cancel' id='cancel_post_edit'>Cancel</button>" +
                        "</form>";
```

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single("file"), function(req, res) {

    const tempPath = req.file.path;
    const targetPath = path.join(__dirname, "./Assets/Images/image.png");

    console.log(req.file);

    if (path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase() === "png"
        || path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase() === "jpg") {

        fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function(err) {

            if (err) res.status(400).send({status: "Failure Internal server error"});
            else res.status(200).send({status: "Success"});
        });
    }
    else {
        fs.unlink(tempPath, function(err) {

            if (err) res.status(400).send({status: "Failure Internal server error"});
            else res.status(403).send({status: "Failure Internal server error"});
        })
    }
})
```

The problem is that this implementation, predictably, redirects the user off the page to the JSON file being returned. Is there any way around this? I have see some suggest writing an .onsubmit function that returns false, and using some sort of JQuery to send the file in that function. I have an .onsubmit function that I'm using to send the text fields directly to the database, and I tried returning false from it and it still redirects, so I feel stuck there as well.

```
form.onsubmit = function() {

    var title = document.getElementById("post_title").value;
    var description = document.getElementById("post_desc").value;
    var price = document.getElementById("post_price").value;

    $.ajax({
        url: "DBRequest",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: { data:
                JSON.stringify(
                { query: "UPDATE post SET title = $1, description = $2, price = $3 WHERE pid = $4",
                  vars: [title, description, price, postID],
                  type: "update"})}
    }).done(function(response) {
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("post_edit_modal"));
        populate();
    });

    return false;
}
```

If the answer to both of the questions is no, then how is this generally done? And is there some place where I can read in detail about how this process works? It seems very common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for anyone else having this problem, here's a general solution I've managed to put together using AJAX:

HTML:

```
<input type='file' id='file' name='file'>
<button type='button' class='submit' id='submit'>Submit</button>
```

Client-side JS:

```
submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.onclick = function() {

    var fileData = $("#file").prop("files")[0];
    var formData = new FormData;
    formData.append("file", fileData);

    $.ajax({
        url: "upload",
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        type: "POST",
    }).done(function(response) {
        //Handle success
    }).catch(function(err) {
        //Handle error
    });
}
```

Server-side JS:

```
let multer = require("multer");

const upload = multer({ dest: "/Images" });

app.post('/upload', upload.single("file"), function(req, res) {

    const tempPath = req.file.path;
    const targetPath = path.join(__dirname, "./Assets/Images/" + req.file.originalname);

    if (path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase() === ".png"
        || path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase() === ".jpg") {

        fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function(err) {

            if (err) res.status(400).send({status: "Failure: Internal server error"});
            else res.status(200).send({status: "Success"});
        });
    }
    else {
        fs.unlink(tempPath, function(err) {

            if (err) res.status(400).send({status: "Failure: Internal server error"});
            else res.status(403).send({status: "Failure: Internal server error"});
        })
    }
})
```

This will upload a single file to Assets/Images if the file is jpg or png.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) is what you're looking for. Preventing the form from reloading the page or taking you anywhere.